# How to validate forms in react "outside" of a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

I am building a [component in React](http://tenuous-territory.surge.sh/) for creating cooking recipes. I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for validating forms. I have two forms on my container. One for adding ingredients with three input fields (name, quantity, unit), and one for steps - with one input field. As I add ingredients or steps, I am validating if input data is correct and block adding item to an list, which is beneath this form if data is not correct. So far so good. But my problem is, I need to access validation process of those two forms with my general "Add recipe" button on bottom of page. For example, if I leave those input fields that are required empty, I want to check that with press on a button "Add recipe" as well, not just with submitting those two "sub-forms".
Here is link to gist: [Link](https://gist.github.com/bmandl/ef2b952323c7c3ca8859d92d14e5ce8b). 
Can someone please look at my code and give me a suggestion.

PS.: I created FormGroupArray component for adding array of FormGroup elements dynamically (I am using react-bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
My main container is now a form. I changed all inputs to uncontrolled type, as they should be with react-hook-form. I am manually validating fields that should be added to list. Here is my solution:
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/bmandl/251ea4a3b2b12b535395ef791e58c5dc)